# How to use multiple [attribute=value] Selector for same element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a bilingual form in which I have a `select` tag with multiple `option` tags inside. I wanna get that option with class "blah" and with value "1" and then select it as "selected" option.

I selected it based on `class` and then select based `value` but the result is null. Here is my code:

```
$('select').each(function (e, item) {

             var selectedEnglish = $(item).children("option[class='English']")
             var englishItem = selectedEnglish.find("option:selected").val();

             var farsiList = $(item).children("option[class='Farsi']")
             var farsiItem = farsiList.find("[value='" + englishItem + "']");

             farsiItem.attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
```

Whats more how can I get with one chain of statements?

this selected is populated in jquery:

```
$("#TitleId").html("");
            $("#TitleId")
                .html("<option value='' class='Farsi'>عنوان</option><option value='' class='English'>Title</option>");
            $.each(titles,
                function (key, value) {
                    $("#TitleId")
                        .html($("#TitleId").html() +
                            "<option class='Farsi' value='" +
                            value.Id +
                            "'>" +
                            value.Name +
                            "</option>"+
                            "<option class='English' value='" +
                            value.Id +
                            "'>" +
                            value.EnName +
                            "</option>");
                });
```

Comment: Can you provide some html for this code?

Comment: just to clarify, do you have one `select` for english and one `select` for farsi?

Comment: @changepicture I have multiple select element. in each "select", there is 2 options with same value for every Item ,but with different class and text. I am going to switch between languages by showing/hiding based on their class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the option with class "blah" and value "1", this is your query:

```
$('select option[class=blah][value="1"]')
```

If you want to select that option you can simply do:

```
$('select option[class=blah][value="1"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: for first time it changes the selected item. but not for second time.

Comment: Unless you are changing the class or value, it should continue to work correctly.  In case you are changing the class or value, you need to update the query accordingly.